# Finding a contradiction to $G$ being abelian when $G\cong M\times L$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-product

I am trying to disprove/prove the following:

"Let $M, L \subseteq G$, $G \cong M \times L$. Then if all the elements of $G$ commute with all the elements of $L$, we have that $G$ is abelian."

For this to be true, it would be necessary that $(ab, cd) = (ba, dc)$,$\ \ \forall a,b \in M, \forall c,d \in L$. As we don't necessarily have $ab=ba$ (since we don't know if $M$ is abelian, then I believe this statement would be false). However I cannot find a counterexample to show this so I'm not sure if I'm perhaps missing out on something.

So I'm just wondering if there's a neat way to disprove/prove the statement, since I can't really seem to find a counter example.

Comment: Is there a reason to not take $L=\{1\}$ and $M=G$, and then just let $G$ be any non-abelian group?

Comment: Elements of $G$ are products of elements from $M$ and $L$. (I am assuming internal direct product.) Then all $m\in M$ and $\ell\in L$ commute, so given an arbitrary element $m\ell$ of $G$ it commutes with all elements of $L$ if and only if $\ell$ commutes with all elements of $L$. That is, the statement is true if and only if $L$ is abelian. However, for $G$ itself to be abelian, that would also require $M$ to be abelian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L=\{e\}$ and $M=D_3$, the dihedral group of order $6$.

Comment: I think you have $L$ and $M$ swapped

Comment: Thank you, @AtticusStonestrom.